# Matching same route / different HTTP verb to different controller method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I’ve got a Rails 3 app where instead of the default destruction mapping:

```
modelname DELETE         /modelname/:id           modelname#destroy
```

I would like a dedicated route with a `GET` ‘fallback’ so that users without Javascript are sent to a confirmation page:

```
delete_modelname DELETE  /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#destroy
delete_modelname GET     /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#confirm_destruction
```

I can get the above output in `rake routes` with the following declaration:

```
resources :modelname, except: [:destroy] do
  member {
    get 'delete', to: 'confirm_destruction'
    delete 'destroy', as: 'delete'
  }
end
```

However, one of the routes does not match, and it seems to be order-dependent, i.e. whichever is defined first then fails to match in testing. I notice that the default ‘overloaded’ routes Rails generates look a bit different in `rake routes`:

```
modelnames GET          /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#index
           POST         /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#create
```

The route name is not repeated, and a link to `create` will become a link to `index` outside a form or a Javascript-enabled request.

It seems I’ve defined two entirely separate routes sharing the same name, rather than overloaded the path as I intended.

What am I missing? Is there any way to get the effect I’m looking for?

**Things I’ve tried**

Since it appeared to be the route *name* which was clashing, I tried this:

```
member {
  get 'delete', to: 'confirm_destruction'
  delete 'destroy', path: 'delete'
}
```

Changing `as:` to `path:` so that the route name would not be affected, but the paths would match. This works! The following routes are generated:

```
delete_modelname GET     /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#confirm_destruction
modelname DELETE         /modelname/:id/delete    modelname#destroy
```

This gives the effect I’m after, but unfortunately the `modelname DELETE` route masks the default `modelname PUT` route for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there is a way to do this, but it’s not quite as elegant as I’d hoped. I’m very open to a better answer if anyone has one.

```
resources :modelname, except: [:destroy] do
  member {
    get 'delete', to: 'confirm_destruction'
    delete 'destroy', as: 'destroy', path: 'delete'
  }
end
```

It works because these two new routes have unique names for using in views – `delete_modelname_path` and `destroy_modelname_path` – but if Javascript is disabled, the `destroy_modelname` path is still `/modelnames/:id/delete`, which comes in as a `GET` request and Rails matches it to the `delete_modelname` route (i.e. the confirmation page).